# Generating auth signature in php

Tags: php, oauth

I have these data:

- Consumer Key
- Consumer Secret
- Token
- Token Secret

And i need to generate a signature to be used in a Header.

My application is in PHP and i tried using [PHP: OAuth::generateSignature()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) to generate the signature as follows:

```
$apiUsername = <my api username>;
$apiPassword = <my api password>;
$token = <token returned from GetAccessToken response>;
$secret = <tokenSecret from GetAccessToken response>;
$time = time();
$endpoint = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/GetBasicPersonalData';

$auth = new \OAuth($apiUsername, $apiPassword);
$auth->setToken($token, $secret);
$auth->setTimestamp($time);

$signature = $auth->generateSignature('POST', $endpoint);
```

But the signature does not work and i get error "Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect."

What is the correct way to generate a signature to be used in headers?